# MVC4 Image optimization caching on demand performance issues

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

**THE QUESTION** Is there some `.net`, `ASP`, `MVC` or even `IIS` optimizations I'm not taking in account? or is this whole approach simply a *bad idea*?

**SCENARIO**

The following **works 0K**

I have an `ImageController` that allows me to optimize and cache images on the fly.

The actual call looks like this: `/image/user/1?width=200&height=200`

And the controller itself like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous] // TODO author/revise
public class ImageController : FileController
{
    private FileResult Image(string entity, long id, int? width, int? height, Position? position=null)
    {
        string file = base.ImageHandler.ImagesPaths(Paths.img, entity, id.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
        {
throw new HttpException(404, "File not found");
        }

    // implicit else
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat oImageFormat = WebFileSystemImageHandler.ImageFormat(extension);

        if ((null != width) || (null != height))
        {
// vvv Beginning of IS THERE SOMETHING WRONG WITH THIS? vvv
            string path       = string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}/", Paths.img, entity, id);
            string pathServer = Server.MapPath(path);
            if (!Directory.Exists(pathServer))
                 Directory.CreateDirectory(pathServer);

            string pattern = "";
            if (null != width ) pattern += width.ToString();        // 500
            if (null != height) pattern += "x" + height.ToString(); // 500x400, or x400 w/o width

            string cache = Directory.GetFiles(pathServer, pattern).FirstOrDefault();
// ^^^ End of IS THERE SOMETHING WRONG WITH THE ABOVE ^^^
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cache))
            {// no cache? sure let's get you started!
                Image oImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(  new MemoryStream( System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file) )  );
                file = Server.MapPath(path + pattern + extension);
                Bitmap oBitmap = new Bitmap(oImage);
                       oBitmap = oBitmap.Adjust(width:width, height:height, position:position);
                       oBitmap = oBitmap.Compress();
                       oBitmap.Save(file, oImageFormat);
            }
            else
                file = cache;
        }
        MemoryStream oStream = new MemoryStream( System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file) );
        string mime = string.Format("image/{0}", extension.Replace(".", ""));
    return new FileContentResult(oStream.ToArray(), mime);
    }
```

Where `base.ImageHandler.ImagesPaths` basically returns a `Directory.GetFiles("{folder}\{entity}\", "{id}.*").FirstOrDefault()`

**THE PROBLEM** When I have a gallery page with multiple of these images, the `html` renders immediately **but** the images show empty and start popping 1 by 1 (I imagine this is due to 1 call to the controller per session). I would expect this as expected behavior **the 1st run only**, but happens **every time**

Comment: If your application is using HttpSession, make sure it is either disabled for this controller or at least read-only, using: [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]. That way at least 2 requests can execute in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side-comment:

If your application is using `HttpSession`, make sure it is either disabled for this `Controller` or at least read-only, using:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

That way at least 2 requests can execute in parallel.

Also, if the amount of images and sizes will be limited and not too large, you might be able to simplify all this by just using `OutputCache` both at the client and the server setting (in memory). You'd avoid writing the images to physical storage, and resized output would get reused between users.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. Can you point me in the direction of this `OutputCache`

Comment: Sure, it's quite simple to use, just decorating your action method with attributes: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs.
In the attribute properties you will also find the Location property, which determines if the caching should be done in the client (browser), server, proxies, etc.

Just take into account that this will cache the result in memory (if you configure it to be on the server as well) for the same url.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advise you use GDI for image resizing at all in MVC, as it's not supported and can cause memory leaks and other issues if not used carefully (see http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/12/10/resizing-images-from-the-server-using-wpf-wic-instead-of-gdi.aspx).

You should look at alternatives such as using Windows Imaging Components, or for simplicity and additional features use Imageresizer (http://imageresizing.net/)

Also see bertrand's follow up posts: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/05/03/the-fastest-way-to-resize-images-from-asp-net-and-it-s-more-supported-ish.aspx
and http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/10/22/state-of-net-image-resizing-how-does-imageresizer-do.aspx for advice on the various approaches to achieving fast web-based resizing

Comment: Seems that my *lags* that I don't like are coming from the actual process of looking for the `cache` itself (I just Updated the question).

 - Is the `Directory.GetFiles` that slow?
 - Should I use `FileStreamResult` instead?